# why is an error popping up saying "unable to write to /usr/local..."

Tags: matlab

[image]

I was trying to install Matlab using file installation key and to keep it in the default folder but above shown error is popping up, any idea how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This installer is probably running as your user and not root or via sudo.

Without that privilege level it won't be allowed to write to system areas such as /usr/

Depending on how that program works you have two options :

1. Install to another folder

try changing the install path to somewhere within your home directory

2. Escalate privileges

instead of clicking on the file go to the terminal and run it via sudo.
Doing this implies a lot of trust in the installer and could damage your system.